# How can I cin an unsigned long long without error?

Tags: c++

OK, so this is my code:

```
    cout << "What is your p value?" << endl;
    unsigned long long p;
    cin >> p;
    cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "What is your q value?" << endl;
    unsigned long long q;
    cin >> q;
            cin.ignore();
    cout << endl;
```

I put the first huge value--that is, p--in, and something gets put in to q automatically even with these `cin.ignore()`'s. What issues am I not seeing here? Please let me know if you need more information if it's not obvious to you.

[Adding information from a comment: the input value was `92896134244099469431`, which exceeds 2<sup>66</sup>.]

Comment: What value are you inputting?  If you are giving erroneous input for q, then `cin` will be put in an error state, and all future operations will fail until the error is cleared (with a call to `cin.clear()`).  Is that what you're experiencing?

Comment: I'm going to wager there's a comma involved. (small wager, it is just a guess after all)

Comment: Please put your full code on a site such as ideone.com

Comment: @Desolator: It's better to put the full code in the question itself. I was able to make the above work just by wrapping it with a few lines to make a complete self-contained program.

Comment: A quick experiment shows that if I run your code and give it an input value much too big to fit in an `unsigned long long`, stores incorrect values in `p` and `q` doesn't let me enter a value for `q`. It seems like the `cin >> p;` stops when it's read too many digits, leaving the rest of the input to be read by `cin >> q;`. Which is why it's important for you to tell us (a) exactly what input you're giving the program and (b) exactly what output it's giving you.

Comment: How huge is huge?  Are you trying to exceed the maximum value of an `unsigned long long` on your system?  That won't end well....

Comment: I had some of the details wrong. `cin >> p;` reads all the digits and sets `p` to a huge value, and then `cin >> q;` doesn't store a value in `q`.  See my answer.

Comment: It is a 20-digit positive integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say you entered a "huge value".  If that value exceeds the upper bound of `unsigned long long`, then `cin >> p;` will fail.

A quick experiment indicates that once that happens, `cin >> q;` doesn't do anything, and no value is stored in `q`.  The value of `p` will probably be `18446744073709551615`, or 2<sup>64</sup>-1.

You need to check whether each input operation succeeded or failed, and decide how to handle any errors.

You also need to update your question to indicate exactly what input you provided to your program.

Comment: I used 92896134244099469431

Comment: I see now what the issue is. Thank you.

Comment: @TyquanPesik: Glad I could help. Your question will be more useful to future viewers if you edit that information into the body of the question.