# Different results for long long int in c and c++?

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to solve a this problem-> [Candy3](http://www.spoj.com/problems/CANDY3/)
We are supposed to use long long to solve this problem. But when I'm using cin to take inputs that are larger than 10^19 (i know it is the limit of long long but the there is limit constraint specified and we are supposed to output the right answer) it is giving random outputs. Whereas, when I'm using scanf() it is printing the correct answer.

This is really weird. What is the difference b/w scanf and cin.
My code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int t,n;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--){
        long long sum=0,sweet;
        cin>>n;
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
            //cin>>sweet; printing yes no randomly
            scanf("%lld", &sweet); // working correctly
            sum = (sum + sweet)%n;
        }
        if(sum)
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
        else
            cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: This is a weird question and it is not specified in the question that what should be the size of input. Here is the input specification -

> "The first line of the input file contains an integer T specifying the
>   number of test cases. Each test case is preceded by a blank line. Each
>   test case looks as follows: The first line contains N : the number of
>   children. Each of the next N lines contains the number of candies one
>   child brought."

Comment: you do cin>> integer but scanf into long long int, right?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I cin an unsigned long long without error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17076517/how-can-i-cin-an-unsigned-long-long-without-error)

Comment: @bits_international looking at the commented code, ``cin >> sweet`` is what used to be there, and ``sweet`` is a ``long long``, and also what ``scanf`` is writing to.

Comment: @amit: please provide a data set that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If you're being told to use `long long` for values up to `10**19`, you're being given bad advice. Are you sure it wasn't `unsigned long long`?

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Given the link of the original question on SPOJ, in my question above.

Comment: @AmitTripathi: none of the numbers in the example given on the link are larger than 11. Are you saying your program fails with that data set?

Comment: @Michael: they are just few test cases. The answer will not be till we make a long long int and use scanf. If you want you can run my code on spoj.com with cin>> and scanf(). !st one will give WA and with second one AC (accepted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As many people have noted, you're attempting to read integers which will overflow a `long long`.

The difference between `scanf` and `cin.operator>>()` with respect to integer overflow is that `scanf` does not (necessarily) test for integer overflow; if the number read is too big, the result is undefined behaviour. It's common that you'll just find an incorrect value in the corresponding argument, but there are no guarantees.

`cin.operator>>()`, on the other hand, *does* check for integer overflow, and if it finds integer overflow, it stores the largest possible integer of the indicated type and puts the `cin` stream into failure state. Once the stream is in failure state, it stays there until the state is cleared; furthermore, any subsequent use of `cin.operator>>()` will do nothing if the stream is in failure state.

Consequently, once you attempt to read an integer which is too large with `cin.operator>>()`, your code will find `sweet` to be the largest possible `long long` on every subsequent read.

So when using C++ formatted input, you need to *always check for failure*, and do something appropriate.

Comment: Thank you-good explanation and now I know why my program was terminating in middle when i was using cin>> for very large inputs whereas scanf() was working fine. I guess, my answer got accepted with scanf() coz it was not terminating in middle for very large inputs. I'm right?

Comment: The point is that cin>> stops reading after an error, including overflow. So the calls to cin>> become no-ops. Sweet doesn't change. n doesn't change. I don't know what you mean by "it prints yes and no together but I suppose it is because it stops reading but keeps on looping, so you get more output than you expect.

Comment: with cin both get printed                                  if(sum)
    cout<<"NO"<<endl;
else
    cout<<"YES"<<endl;

Answer (score 3):

You say you're entering values bigger than 10<sup>19</sup>. That will probably overflow a `long long`.

Type `long long` is guaranteed to be at least 64 bits wide, and on every compiler I've seen it's *exactly* 64 bits wide. That means the maximum possible value of a `long long` is 2<sup>63</sup>-1, or 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, which is approximately 9 * 10<sup>18</sup>.

If you enter a value of 10<sup>19</sup>, or 10,000,000,000,000,000, it will overflow. If `cin << ...` encounters a numeric overflow, it will fail; you haven't checked for that.

I don't believe that using `scanf` will solve this problem. `scanf` has undefined behavior if it reads a number outside the range of the specified type; storing a garbage value is a likely outcome. I can only guess that you're happen to be entering a smaller number with the `scanf` version of your program than with the `cin  >> ...` version, and didn't notice that you were doing so.

You can use somewhat larger values (at the cost of not being able to store negative values) by using type `unsigned long long`, which has a minimum value of 0 and a maximum of at least 2<sup>64</sup>-1, or 18,446,744,073,709,551,615, approximately 1.8 * 10<sup>19</sup>.

If you need even larger numbers, you might consider using floating-point, which gives you a much larger range at the expense of losing precision for large values.

Comment: @KeithThompson :Yes, i know a value bigger than 10^18 will overflow. but when I'm entering a value greater than 10^18 with scanf output is either yes or no whereas, when I'm using cin>> then it prints both yes and no together. Also, when I submitted this code with cin>> on SPOJ got wrong answer but with scanf() got AC(with the same code). You can even check it on SPOJ.

Comment: If `scanf` reads an out-of-range value, its behavior is undefined. There's no particular reason to expect it to be consistent. You just need to fix the code so its behavior isn't undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to test small numbers such as 5, for example ? If it's working it's probably something in the number you enter which is probably out of the maximum that `long long int` can contain. Just try doing this on your system:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long long int>::max() << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

and check if the value you entered is bigger than the one printed. If so, just declare a variable with enough space for the value, if the value printed is above the value you entered and there's STILL an error, comment on this post.

Comment: Basically, I'm getting the right answer for small values. But when I'm entering a value greater than 10^18 with scanf output is either yes or no whereas, when I'm using cin>> then it prints both yes and no together. Why this weird output and whats the difference that one get accepted and other one gives the Wrong Answer.

Comment: @AmitTripathi Exactly 10^18 ? Like, 10^18 works and (10^18)+1 doesn't ? Scanf can cause a buffer overflow so it's possible that he stored the number entered even OUTSIDE the boundary of the 'long long' variable in memory. What does the code I mentioned above print you ?

Comment: it printed 9223372036854775807.

Comment: as u and rici has said Scanf can cause a buffer overflow so it's possible that it stored the number entered even OUTSIDE the boundary of the 'long long' maybe this is the reason that scanf works for very large input.

Comment: Just to be sure - try inputting 9223372036854775807 (just right before the boundary)

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered this problem, and you can get an ac by `scanf` and get an error by `cin` because of the example is special. In fact, if there is an overflowing, using these two input methods will also be wrong.
    For `long long` type, for question I encountered at "[A+B and C (64bit)](https://pintia.cn/problem-sets/994805342720868352/problems/994805406352654336)", if we use the example data "`9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 0`" to A B C, we can get the error answer by the `cin` and get the correct answer by `scanf`;However, if we use the example data "`9223372036854775808 -9223372036854775808 -1`" to A B C, we can get the correct answer by cin and get the error answer by scanf.
    So we should use another method to solve the problem.(or the input data is in ( 2<sup>-63</sup>, 2<sup>63</sup> ), and the input data will be legal.)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.